# Word formation of "perceive"

Tags: word-request

This comes from a word formation exercise. I have to fill in the gaps with a word formed from "perceive".

> It was... of you to notice that on the spot.

I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is: It was *perceptive* of you to notice that on the spot.

The word *perceptive*  is an adjective and means *having sensitive insight* .

Word Family: perceive - verb / perception - noun / perceptive - adjective